# Tensorflow Serving using GPU on AWS EC2 GPU instance with Deep Learning AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, gpu, tensorflow-serving

I am running a model using pre-installed tensorflow_model_server (refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-tfserving.html)) on AWS EC2 GPU instance with Deep Learning AMI, but it's only using CPU when I am running a client.

Is there any way I can make the pre-installed tensorflow_model_server use GPU for the predictions?